# Nested arguments for Ansible Module

Tags: module, ansible

I am developing an Ansible module. Is it possible to specify a set of arguments as *required* when one argument has a certain value?

For example, if my module has a 'state' argument that can be either 'present' or 'absent', is it possible to require an additional set of arguments like 'type', 'path' only when state=present?

```
module_args = dict(
   name=dict(type='str', required=True),
   type=dict(type='str', required=False),
   path=dict(type='str', required=False),
   state=dict(type='str', required=False, choices=["present","absent"]
}

module = AnsibleModule(
   argument_spec=module_args,
   supports_check_mode=True
)

name = module.params["name"]
script_type = module.param["type"]
path = module.param["path"]
state = module.state["state"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such ability in current Ansible 2.3.

There is only `required_together` option for `AnsibleModule` class to define parameters that should be supplied together (but there is no condition on its value):

```
 required_together = [['s3_key', 's3_bucket'],
                     ['vpc_subnet_ids', 'vpc_security_group_ids']]
```

So you should do manual checks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if too late, but you can do exactly this with the following.

```
module_args = dict(
   name=dict(type='str', required=True),
   type=dict(type='str', required=False),
   path=dict(type='str', required=False),
   state=dict(type='str', required=False, choices=["present","absent"]
)

required_if_args = [
   ["state", "present", ["type", "path"]]
]

module = AnsibleModule(
   argument_spec=module_args,
   required_if=required_if_args,
   supports_check_mode=True
)
```

This states that if state=present, type and path are required.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no such concept as *nested parameters* in Ansible (AFAIK), there are other concepts that may accomplish the same intent:

- required_together
- required_one_of
- required_if

With the above declarations, one can make associations between parameters -- that is put in logic where if one parameter is specified, another may be asked to be specified with it.

Or if a certain value is specified for a parameter (i.e. State=present), additional parameters may be asked to be specified with that parameter (given its value).

Joe Seeder's [blogpost](http://mobygeek.net/blog/2016/02/16/ansible-module-development-parameters/) covers this in more detail.